# Permissions required for Get Data from Salesforce Reports from Excel

Tags: permissions, excel, salesforceexcelconnector

MS Excel (Enterprise for Windows) has a handy tool to get Get Data from Salesforce Objects / Reports (via Power Query).

This works well for me (with Sys Admin permissions), but my colleagues are getting an error during authentication. "We [i.e. Salesforce] do not support this Browser." (MS Excel / Power Query appears to use IE11 for this authentication window, which SF does not support. (Same issue discussed [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Salesforce-Authentication-We-don-t-support-this-browser/m-p/831736)))

Given I can access this function without this authentication / browser error, I think the core issue here is the permissions required to extract data using this function.

[This](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/salesforceobjects) documentation suggests all it needs is the **API Enabled** system permission. But my users have that via their Profile & Permission Sets.

So... does anyone know what other Salesforce permissions might be required? I hope not full SysAdmin.

Comment: Hi @steviep, May I know the report which need to export via Power Query has available in private folder or public folder in Salesforce?

Comment: @MohanRaj The reports are in Public Folders, but users typically don't have access to Reports in Public Folders... access is managed via Sharing to Public Groups.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's weird for me too. 
Following System Permission "View Reports in Public Folders" provide access to the users who need to view reports in public folder. So please give a try the in the above permission also if you time :)

Comment: @MohanRaj My users don't have the View Reports in Public Folders permission, but can access all reports' data via Excel/PowerQuery.

Answer (score 0):

After much investigation through trial and error, I have discovered the permission required for this to work.

For some reason that I don't really understand, the required permission is.... drumroll...

```
Manage Users
```